# Is it safe to concatenate two XPath 1.0 queries?

Tags: xpath

If I have two XPath queries where the second one is meant to further drill down the result of the first, can I safely let my script combine them into a single query by...

1. placing parenthesis around the first query,
2. prefixing the second query with with a slash, and then
3. simply concatenating the two strings ?

### Context

The concrete usecase that sparked this question involves extracting information from XML/XHTML documents according to externally supplied pairs of *"CSS selector + attribute name"* using XPath behind the scenes.

For example the script may get the following as input:

**selector:** `a#home, a.chapter`
**attribute:** `href`

It then compiles the selector to an XPath query using the [HTML::Selector::XPath](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aSelector%3a%3aXPath) Perl module, and the attribute by simply prefixing a `@` ... which in this case would yield:

**XPath query 1:** `//a[@id='home'] | //a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' chapter ')]`
**XPath query 2:** `@href`

And then it repeatedly passes those queries to [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/)'s XPath engine to extract the requested information (in this example, a list of URLs) from the XML documents in question.

It works, but I would prefer to combine the two queries into a single one, which would simplify the code for invoking them and reduce the performance overhead:

**XPath query:** `(//a[@id='home'] | //a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' chapter ')])/@href`

(note the added parenthesis and slash)

But is this safe to do programmatically, for arbitrary input queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, you can't concatenate two arbitrary XPath expressions in this way, especially not in XPath 1.0. It's easy to find counter-examples: in XPath 1.0 you can't even have a union expression on the RHS of '/', so concatenating "/a" and "(b|c)" would fail.

In XPath 2.0, the result will always be syntactically valid, but in may contain type errors, e.g. if the expressions are "count(a)" and "b". The LHS operand of "/" must evaluate to a sequence of nodes.

Comment: What if the conditions are like in the particular use-case described below the question, i.e. the LHS is guaranteed to match a list of element nodes (because that's the only thing that CSS selectors can match, right?), and the RHS is always a simple attribute name?

Comment: The question said "for arbitrary input queries". Obviously there is some subset for which it will work.

Comment: And I'm wondering what that subset it... You mentioned union expressions on the RHS and non-nodelist expressions on the LHS as examples for what will not work. Anything else?

Comment: The grammar is `FilterExpr '/' RelativeLocationPath`. A FilterExpr allows any expression provided it's in parentheses. A RelativeLocationPath is much more limited: it's basically a sequence of Steps separated by '/', where a step is something like child::* with optional predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this should work. However, you will always have to respect the correct context. If the elements in your example in the first query have no `href` attribute, you will get an empty result set.

Also, you will have to take care of e.g. a leading slash in front of your second query, so that you don't end up with a descendant-or-self axis step, which might not be what you want. Apart from that, this should always work - The worst that can happen that it is not logical correct (i.e. you don't get the expected result), but it should always be valid XPath.